# System completely hangs sometimes on an Asus X54H

Tags: grub2, bios

I have installed `Ubuntu 11.04` through `USB stick` on my `Asus X54H` laptop.Every thing is going fine but sometimes the `system hangs up with the complete black screen`,after that it does not respond any keys.Can some one tell me how it is doing like this?How to solve this?Any help will be highly appreciable.

Comment: I think your laptop is going to more heated. So it can be hanged.

Comment: Nope..I don't think like that.I have checked that issue..

Comment: Have you noticed when your system goes hang means on some particular tasks or after a fixed time period.

Comment: no..It hangs anytime..Sometimes it hangs without any tasks just by in ideal conditions

Comment: It may be due to RAM. If you can open your laptop then remove RAM, clean it and placed again. I hope your problem might be solved.

Comment: Actually the laptop is the new one and one thing it is running smooth with windows 7 .

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you are using 11.04? With the new release of 12.04 out, perhaps it's worth trying a more up to date version.

Comment: The same version is working good with another system so I think there is no problem  with that I think.

Answer (score 0):

If using unity then try `unity --reset`. Else Observe if system hangs up on starting particular application. Also just try making new user account and use that (Some user specific setting might have gone wrong).

Comment: how to make `unity --reset`.I don't have any idea about that.Can you describe that?

Comment: if you are using ubuntu then `ctrl+alt+t` for terminal. It can be even found under accessories.

Answer (score 0):

Many people had this problem with ASUS(boots to black screen)

Try this:

Go to BIOS > Security> I / O interface Security> "New interface card". Set it to Locked.

I also had this problem before but after I did that Ubuntu worked.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1662577&page=3